# contextMenu needed only for locked columns in a datagrid

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

What would be the best way to go about this - need context menu items only on certain columns (locked columns) of a datagird and not on the other columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it working by including this in code:

```
_context.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_SELECT, onMenuSelect);//_context is the dataprovider of the contextMenu of the datagird
```

then inside onMenuSelect

checking the condition like this:

```
var obj:Object=event.mouseTarget;
if (obj.listData.columnIndex < 10)//where 10 is the locked columns index of the datagrid
{
}
```

Thanks.